# Pattern for updating editable list of elements with Observable

Tags: angular, design-patterns, rxjs, reactive-programming, observable

Technology background: Angular (4) with RxJS in TypeScript. But I believe problem is quite technology independent.

I have an array of elements. That array is provided by service, possibly from remote API (backend).

ElementService:

```
  private elements: Element[];
  private elementsSource = new ReplaySubject<Element[]>(1);
  elementsObservable$ = this.elementsSource.asObservable();
```

Component subscribes to that observable and populates HTML list with data. Now each element of the list can be independly edited by user. After edit change must be saved and sent to a) backend, b) other components that subscribe for changes of that elements.

Because list elements may be edited and they can be "dirty", I don't want to show changes right away with 2-way data binding in other components. Because of this I copy output of observable and work on this copy, and then send update with new list to the service.

ElementListComponent:

```
  elements: Element[];

  constructor(private elementService: ElementService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscribeElements();
  }

  private subscribeElements() {
    this.elementService.getElements().subscribe(elements => this.elements = clone(elements));
  }

  private onChangeSave() {
    this.elementService.updateElements(clone(this.elements));
  }
```

But elements list can be also edited in other components / by other users. In such case ElementService will get update by websocket with new data. This will be sent to ElementListComponent by observable.

Now if:

- user A will start editing one or more items and user B will update some other elements, or
- user will start editing one element X in one component and then edit element Y in other component, or
- user will start editing elements X and Y, save changes to element X (save buttons are independent for elements on the list),

then unsaved changes will be lost as list will be replaced by new, updated one.

I thought about iterating over the array in subscribe() and updating every element separately in local array - adding new elements, removing missing ones, updating changed if they are not edited right now. This way the reference to the array would not change and dirty elements would not be "resetted".

Is this really the best way? Or am I missing something?

Comment: is there a particular reason you're using a replay subject rather than say a plain subject or behaviour subject?

Comment: Yea, I use this as cold observable, that will be initiated for first observer and will return cached value for all next. Different components connects to this observable in my case and I wan't to return last, most fresh value to new client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I came with a solution. Instead of providing full array with Elements by Observable, I emit one event per Element at first and then one per later Element creation / update / delete.

ElementService:

```
@Injectable()
export class ElementService {

  private elementsSource = new ReplaySubject<ElementChange>();
  /** Observable that returns separate observable for each subscriber with independent copies of emitted items. */
  private elementsObservable = Observable.defer(() => this.elementsSource.asObservable().map(x => <ElementChange>clone(x)));

  constructor(private logger: Logger) { }

  /**
   * Returns observable that emits new value on every change (add, update or remove) of every single Element entity.
   * Each observer receives independent copy of entity. New observers receives full history of entities - all events emitted from the beginning
   * of obserable's work.
   */
  getElements(): Observable<ElementChange> {
    return this.elementsObservable;
  }

  createOrUpdateElements(element: Element) {
    if (!element.id) { // generate id for new instance
      element.id = uniqid();
    }

    this.elementsSource.next(new ElementChange(element));
  }

  removeElemenet(element: Element) {
    if (element.id) {
      this.elementsSource.next(new ElementChange(element, true));
    } else {
      this.logger.warn("Cannot emit remove event for unknown Element without ID. Element should be first created by method of this service.", element);
    }
  }

}

/** Model for Element changes emiting by Observable. */
export class ElementChange {
  constructor(public data: Element, public remove: boolean = false) { };
}
```

ElementComponent:

```
export class ElementComponent implements OnInit {

  private elements = new Array<Element>();

  constructor(private elementService: ElementService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscribeElements();
  }

  private subscribeElements() {
    this.elementService.getElements()
      .groupBy(change => change.remove)
      .subscribe(group => {
        if (group.key === false) { // adding / updating
          group
            .map(change => change.data)
            .subscribe(element => {
              let idx = this.elements.findIndex(e => e.id === element.id);
              if (idx === -1) { // add
                this.elements.push(element);
              } else { // update
                this.elements[idx] = element;
              }
            });
        } else { // removing
          group
            .map(element => this.elements.findIndex(e => e.id === element.data.id))
            .filter(idx => idx !== -1)
            .subscribe(idx => {
              this.elements.splice(idx, 1);
            });
        }
      });
  }

  private addAddElementClick() {
    this.elements.push(new Element());
  }

  private onElementSave(element: Element) {
    this.elementService.createOrUpdateElements(element);
  }

  private onElementEditCancel(idx: number) {
    this.removeIfLocalOnlyEntity(idx);
  }

  private onElementRemove(idx: number) {
    this.removeIfLocalOnlyEntity(idx) || this.elementService.removeElemenet(this.elements[idx]);
  }

  /**
   * Removes Element from array if it's local only entity, created locally and never sent to service.
   * @param idx Index of entity in elements array
   * @returns True if entity was removed, false otherwise.
   */
  private removeIfLocalOnlyEntity(idx: number): boolean {
    if (this.elements[idx].id === undefined) {
      this.elements.splice(idx, 1);
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

}
```

**Pros:**

- As long as two users / components do not modify the same Element, they can be worked on (added, edited, removed) without discarding other changes.
- Element instances are cloned for each observer. Thanks to this object modification in one component will not be visible in another until `ElementService#createOrUpdateElements()` method will be explicitly called.

**Cons:**

- Emitted Elements are wrapped in another class with `remove` flag.
- Long subscription implementation in `ElementComponent#subscribeElements()`. It could be shorter using `if` clauses instead of `groupBy()` (by half of lines), but this way it's more readable and easy to extend.

---

**Bonus**

When new Observer subscribes he gets all the past events. Some of them may refer to the same Element (for example add element, modify it, modify it again), but our `ElementComponent` needs only the last one. So `ReplaySubject` may be replaced with custom `ReplayLastDistinctSubject`:

```
/**
 * Subject that emits only last distinct instance of each item that was emitted by the source Observable(s),
 * regardless of when the observer subscribes. After subscription all new items are normally emitted to the Observer,
 * even if they are not distinct. This way on subsciption Observer gets only the latest version of each emitted item so far
 * and then gets all new emits.
 * 
 * Besides distinct filtering the ReplayLastDistinctSubject behaves similary to the ReplaySubject.
 * 
 * Method of comparing items can be specified by providing specific key selector.
 */
export class ReplayLastDistinctSubject<T> extends Subject<T> {

  private values: T[] = [];

  constructor(private keySelector: (value: T) => any = (x) => x) {
    super();
  }

  protected _subscribe(subscriber: Subscriber<T>): Subscription {
    const subscription = super._subscribe(subscriber);
    if (subscription && !(<ISubscription>subscription).closed) {

      const len = this.values.length;
      for (let i = 0; i < len && !subscriber.closed; i++) {
        subscriber.next(this.values[i]);
      }
    }
    return subscription;
  }

  next(value: T) {
    this.addNewDistinctValue(value);
    super.next(value);
  }

  private addNewDistinctValue(value: T) {
    this.values = this.values.filter(x => this.keySelector(x) !== this.keySelector(value));
    this.values.push(value);
  }
}
```

Using `ReplayLastDistinctSubject` new subscriber will get only last past event for each Element, so it won't do uneccessary operations for old versions of Elements.

Any thoughts, comments or better ideas are very welcome :-)

Answer (score -1):

Consider [Mediator](http://www.design-patterns-stories.com/patterns/Mediator/) pattern.
Mediator defines object that controls how set of objects interacts.
Control tower on airport is real life example of Mediator. Each airplane communicates with the tower, so tower has all neccesary information's.

Comment: Well, here the Service acts as Mediator. Problem is in data it serves each of the Colleagues. Serving all new data to Colleague makes it lose his "dirty" changes.